# A promise chain failed to handle a rejection in MVC5

Tags: c#, json, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, runtime-error

I have the following validation method and the associated model class. I am getting the above mentioned error (Title of the Question) in my browser while clicking on the submit button for Create.

How can I resolve the particular issue?

Model Class

```
public class LsystemFamily
{
    public int LsystemFamilyID { get; set; }
    [Display (Name = "Family Name")]
    [Remote("DuplicateFamilyName","LsystemFamilies",HttpMethod = "POST",ErrorMessage= "System Family Name already Exists",AdditionalFields= "LsystemFamilyID")]
    //[Unique(ErrorMessage = "Family Name Already Exists")]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
```

Validation Method

```
    public JsonResult DuplicateFamilyName(string FamilyName, int FamilyID)
    {
        //bool idExists = db.LsystemFamily.Any(id=>id.LsystemFamilyID.Equals(FamilyID));
        if (FamilyID == 0)
        {
            bool exists = db.LsystemFamily.Any(x => x.FamilyName == FamilyName);
            //var name = db.LsystemFamily.Where(x => x.FamilyName.Equals(FamilyName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(!exists,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            bool exists = db.LsystemFamily.Where(x => x.LsystemFamilyID != FamilyID).Any(x => x.FamilyName == FamilyName);
            //var name = db.LsystemFamily.Where(x => x.FamilyName.Equals(FamilyName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && x.LsystemFamilyID != FamilyID).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(!exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The validation method is posted because I started getting the error only after adding the Json Validation.

EDIT : View

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LsystemFamilyID);

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamilyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamilyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FamilyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescriptionEN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DescriptionEN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescriptionEN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescriptionDE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DescriptionDE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescriptionDE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
   </div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: missing your client code script, and the mentioned error, please update your question

Comment: Added the View and the error is the one mentioned in the title , Updated the question @WinterMute